# Get a faster response for a ping

Tags: debian, networking, systemd, ping, sysctl

I noticed that the answer to my ping is slower in one debian machine that another.

For the first one when i ping to 8.8.8.8:

```
 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=29.6 ms
```

For the second one:

```
 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=6.77 ms
```

It's 4 times faster. So how can i make this answer faster ? Which network parameters should i modify to get better response ?

Comment: Looking at the TTLs, the second machine is three hops closer to the target, so no surprise. You should use `tracepath` or similar to examine delays for every hop on the network path.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do anything on the computer itself to make ping latency lower, because the network distance from `8.8.8.8` is different between these two computers. Most of the latency is caused by the intermediate hops between your computer and `8.8.8.8`.

You can use `traceroute 8.8.8.8` command to see more details on the network latency for every hop on the path to the `8.8.8.8` server.